# amazon S3 and android

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I am trying to write an application that downloads pictures from amazon s3 server and presents the pictures as a slideshow on the application. The application will be bundled to a tablet device specifically for this purpose. The device will use wifi connection to check the S3 server for pictures and download them for slideshow. The main problem is making a connection to the s3 server and download the pictures.i have no idea where to start, so my question is this how do i make a connection to s3 server for download programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to download the AWS SDK for Android: http://aws.amazon.com/pt/sdkforandroid/
and read its documentation. It is really simple to use its API.

After you have all your SDK and token configured at the server and your code, all you will need is a call like this to download a picture from S3:

```
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(AWSCredentials);
S3Object object = s3.getObject(bucketName, pictureId);
object.getObjectContent();
```

But read the documentation, the full configuration requires quite a lot of work.