# Storing data online ANDROID

Tags: android, xml, json, cloud, storage

I am pretty confused and lost in all the documentation.

What I want to do is store a number of objects online (less than 20 Mb). The app that I am developing should be able to retrieve those objects ( preferable JSON but XML would do) and perhaps upload other such objects.

From what I see, the Google Cloud storage is not free. Is there anything that does what I need and is also free? If not, can you point me to the right documentation to achieve what I want? I have been looking into the topic for a couple of days and I am still lost between buckets, the Cloud JSON API, Cloud Storage, all these being new to me.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have just 20 MB of data then you may use [Parse](https://parse.com/tutorials) for storing data upto 1Gb for free. Also see https://parse.com/products/data. I heard from those who used it, that the API is also straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking fore, but dropbox provides a great android api: http://www.dropbox.com  You can upload/download/modify files pretty easily.  However, this would not be the best solution onless you want to give user's the ability to sign into their own dropbox and save/modify files on a per-user basis. It seems like you might be looking for something more like Amazon s3 storage: http://aws.amazon.com/s3/  . It is a very popular cloud storage provider, and you get 5 gigs free (I think), plus it should be simple to integrate with android.  see here [amazon S3 and android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473574/amazon-s3-and-android) and here: http://aws.amazon.com/pt/sdkforandroid/